# How to print string instead of numbers

Tags: c++

I have this program called Truth Table. How can I print "T" and "F" instead of 1 and 0?
Here are some of the code

```
string Choice, UserInput, NotChoice;
bool FirstChoice[2] = { true, false };
bool ValidInput = false;

bool InvertChoice = false;

cout<<"Enter a Hypothesis: ";
cin>>Choice;
do
{
    ValidInput = false;
    cout<<"Do you want to NOT "<<Choice<<"?(Y/N): ";
    cin>>UserInput;
    toUpper(UserInput);
    if (UserInput == "Y") 
    {   
        InvertChoice = true; ValidInput = true;
    }
    else if (UserInput == "N")
    {
        InvertChoice = false; ValidInput = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"ERROR: Please enter valid values [Y, N]" << endl;
    }
}
while (!ValidInput);

NotChoice = "~" + Choice;

cout<< Choice << (InvertChoice? " | ":"") <<(InvertChoice? NotChoice : "" )<<endl;

for ( int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    bool FirstValue = InvertChoice ? !FirstChoice[x] : FirstChoice[x];
    for ( int z = 0; z < 1; z++ )
    {
        if ( InvertChoice == true )
        {
            cout<< setw(1) << FirstChoice[x] << " | " << FirstValue << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<< setw(1) << FirstChoice[x] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print it like this

Q | ~Q

T | F

F | T

and this is the actual output

Q | ~Q

1 | 0

0 | 1

Comment: Alright! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::boolalpha` to print "true" and "false".

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << true;
```

Or select a string based on bool value

```
bool x = true;
std::cout << (x ? "T" : "F");
```